# Positioning and size of a strange div

Tags: html, css, position

I recently had a problem that seems simple enough to solve but I just can not understand.

I was creating a style swicher and therefore I have included a list with different colors and another div colorSwicher connected to the plugin.
I do not understand why, despite the div is after the list, appears as the first.
And considering its size, has a width of proportion.

How can I insert it after the other? And most of all I would like to understand why it has this effect ..

Thanks in advance

[image: Problem width for no reason]

The html is

```
<div id="option">
    <ul>
        <li id="blue" class="color"></li>
        <li id="red"class="color"></li>
        <li id="yellow" class="color"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="colorSelector"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

The css is

```
#colorSelector {
position: relative;
max-width: 36px;
height: 36px;
background: url(../images/select.png);
}

#colorSelector div {
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
left: 3px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: url(../images/select.png) center;
}
```

For the ALL code : http://jsfiddle.net/zh3sL/

I added another div with the same id to show how its width involves the whole screen even though it is set to 36px

[image: effect 2]

I tried to eliminate the position, but the result is not the best
[image: Without positon]

I hope someone can understand and can help me.

Again, thanks in advance

Comment: With only the code you've posted is not enough to reproduce your problem

Comment: Put your code in a fiddle so we can try help you.

Comment: Remove position:absolute

Comment: it will be good if you put your code in jsfiddel.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone ... here is the link  http://jsfiddle.net/zh3sL/

Comment: I showed the div in question in an other location in order to better understand

Answer (score 0):

assuming the li's are floated left and the ul is not clearing the floats, how about putting an overflow:hidden on the ul?

Also, the position absolute on #colorSelector will not be doing you any favours. either float that too, or leave it as display block (no float or position absolute).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid you do not understand well what you mean.

In code like that?

Sorry to bother you

Comment: I showed the div in question in an other location in order to better understand

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing "position" attribute from "#colorSelector" and "#colorSelector div" selection. And then you can add "float: left" to both of them. Also add "padding: 0;" to "ul".

Comment: I made ​​the change as you suggested and I thank you .. but the 'effect is not what you expected as you can see with the image